# number of times that condition is true [javascript]

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

This is probably a really noob question. I tried to search but probably i´m not asking google the right words.

What i want to get is the number of times that the:

-number 3 exist

-number 2 exist

-number 43 exist

I could do it manually if the array has a fixed values, but the problem is that the array will be changing a lot, with completely different numbers.

i will leave a img here if the text is not explicit enough :D

[image]

```js
var a = [2,3,3,3,2,43];
var t = [...new Set(a)];

for ( var k = 0, l = t.length; k < l; k ++ ) {
 for ( var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
 
  if (a[i] == t[k]) {
 
  console.log(k);  
 }
};

};
```

Comment: You are printing out the index, you need to keep a counter for each one. Also, `new Set(a)` will remove all the duplicates, you'll never get the right counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code. Basically, you just need to loop through the array of numbers then count the occurrences.

```js
let counts = {};
let nums = [2,3,3,3,2,43];

for(let num of nums) {
  counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answer. Work perfectly. I just changed the console.log line. so if somebody come here they get 100% what i want.

Thank a lot Lewis

```js
let counts = {};
let nums = [2,3,3,3,2,43];

for(let num of nums) {
  counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(Object.values(counts));
```